Grouping on Multiple Columns then finding unique rows based on max
I have a data frame with 3 columns, 'Supplier', 'Category', and 'Amount'. This df is the result of a grouping operation where I grouped by Supplier, Category, and summed the Amounts. There are still many instance where there are multiple rows per supplier where they used different categories and had different amounts per category. What I'm hoping to do is filter the df so that only the category with the maximum amount per supplier is remaining. I've tried implementing this as part of the groupby, but hasn't worked, I've also followed tutorials where it shows using the .max() operation, but that results in a single line that shows the highest amount in the entire df. Any assistance would be appreciated - I can't share the actual data, but here is an example of what the df looks like now:

And what I would like the resulting df to look like:


Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Please show what you tried. It seems like groupby('SN') and max('Amount') should have worked.

UPDATE: this solution is not correct please check user19077881 answer.

You can slice the dataframe by using the informatioa from GroupBy:
g = df.groupby("SN")["Amount"].max()
df = df.loc[df["SN"].isin(g.index) & df["Amount"].isin(g.values)].reset_index(drop=True)
display(df)

    SN  Category    Amount
0   1   Cat2        3000
1   2   Cat22       5000


Thank you - this looks like it worked

@user2981194 this approach is incorrect. If by chance a row has a value that is equal to the maximum of another group it will be selected. Also, the df["SN"].isin(g.index) filter is useless, it should return all True, and it certainly won't pair the values with the amount.

@mozway could you give an example where it doesn't work? If I put 5000 on the 2nd row  instead of 3000 I get the correct result.

@rehaqds try with df = pd.DataFrame({'SN': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 'Amount': [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]}) for example. This will incorrectly select all rows in SN 1.

Or with OP's example, change 3000 to 4500 and get an extra row in SN 2.

@mozway correct, I missed that. user2981194, the other post would deserve to be the accepted one!

You can directly obtain the index of the maximum rows and use this to select those rows:
df2 = df.iloc[df.groupby('SN')['Amount'].idxmax(),:].reset_index(drop = True)

which gives:
   SN Category  Amount
0   1     Cat2    3000
1   2    Cat22    5000


Thanks for posting, I'll try this as well.

@user2981194 this is a correct approach
